# Select User Broken in Concrete5.7 Composer

Tags: concrete5

I am having issues with Concrete5's Build-In 'User' Property on the composer form for new pages. When clicking "Select User" the page navigates to `http://website.com/ccm/system/dialogs/user/search`. But that page is completely blank.

When you go into the attributes tab and click "Select User" under "Author" it also has the URL `http://website.com/ccm/system/dialogs/user/search`, but instead of reopening the page, it launches the user selector within the current page. This, I believe, is accomplished using the following JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $("#ccm-user-selector-uID").dialog();
    $("#ccm-user-selector-uID").on('click', function() {
        var selector = $(this);
        ConcreteEvent.unsubscribe('UserSearchDialogSelectUser.core');
        ConcreteEvent.subscribe('UserSearchDialogSelectUser.core', function(e, data) {
            var par = selector.parent().find('.ccm-summary-selected-item-label'),
            pari = selector.parent().find('[name=uID]');
            par.html(data.uName);
            pari.val(data.uID);
            e.stopPropagation();
            jQuery.fn.dialog.closeTop();
        });
        ConcreteEvent.subscribe('UserSearchDialogAfterSelectUser', function(e) {
            jQuery.fn.dialog.closeTop();
        });
    });
});
```

The 'User' option in the Composer has very similar JavaScript associated with it, replacing only the selectors.

```
$(function() {
    $("#ccm-user-selector-ptComposer[13][user]").dialog();
    $("#ccm-user-selector-ptComposer[13][user]").on('click', function() {
        var selector = $(this);
        ConcreteEvent.unsubscribe('UserSearchDialogSelectUser.core');
        ConcreteEvent.subscribe('UserSearchDialogSelectUser.core', function(e, data) {
            var par = selector.parent().find('.ccm-summary-selected-item-label'),
            pari = selector.parent().find('[name=ptComposer[13][user]]');
            par.html(data.uName);
            pari.val(data.uID);
            e.stopPropagation();
            jQuery.fn.dialog.closeTop();
        });
        ConcreteEvent.subscribe('UserSearchDialogAfterSelectUser', function(e) {
            jQuery.fn.dialog.closeTop();
        });
    });
});
```

I can't find anything that is keeping the functionality form working as expected on the Composer section, like it does on the Attributes section when creating a new page.

Has anyone else run into this or have any ideas on what might be the problem?

Comment: I'm not able reproduce this problem in my installation of c5.7.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was related to the two following lines:

```
$("#ccm-user-selector-ptComposer[13][user]").dialog();
$("#ccm-user-selector-ptComposer[13][user]").on('click', function() {
```

They aren't valid ID's and thus jQuery couldn't find them. A hacky solution to solve the issue was to replace lines 38 and 39 in `concrete/src/Form/Service/Widget/UserSelector.php` with

```
$("[id='ccm-user-selector-{$fieldName}']).dialog();
$("[id='ccm-user-selector-{$fieldName}']).on('click', function() {
```

Which allows for it to search out any elements that have an ID that matches that string.